# Typings install gives 'No dependencies' as output

Tags: json, ionic2, typescript-typings

I am trying to install a Ionic 2 template.

Following the readme gets until the point where I need to install typings dependencies. After the installation of the typings CLI with `npm install typings --global`, I should install all the dependencies stated in the typings.json package (already provided by the template in the project folder).

This is how the typings.json file looks like:

```
{
"dependencies": {},
 "devDependencies": {},
 "ambientDependencies": {
 "cordova": "registry:dt/cordova#0.0.0+20160316155526",
 "cordova/plugins/statusbar": "registry:dt/cordova/plugins/statusbar#0.0.0+20160316155526",
 "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#4de74cb527395c13ba20b438c3a7a419ad931f1c"
 }
}
```

As stated in the title, it gives me `No dependencies` as output and it doesn not install anything contained in that config file.

Could it be something related to having installed typings with sudo as a global package? Maybe it is looking for a config file in another directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely the update from 0.* to 1.*. Check the release notes
https://github.com/typings/typings/releases/tag/v1.0.0

> Changes
>
> Many breaking changes (see https://github.com/typings/core/releases/tag/v1.0.0)
>
> - Renamed ambient to global
> - Updated typings/ directory structure (removed browser.d.ts by default, should use typings/index.d.ts by default)
> - Killed defaultAmbientSource (no more auto-install of DefinitelyTyped when using --ambient, explicitly use dt~)
> - Replace ! parser expansion symbol with ~ (! is a reserved bash symbol)
>     Ability to specify different resolutions and output directories using resolution in typings.json
>
> Using tslint-config-standard for linting rules

Fixing it for me was just replacing "devDependencies" with "globalDependencies" in my typings.json.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to install node.js again (there was a newer version when I installed it again, 6.2.0) with the installer, node-sass with npm (I don't know if you need this one) and then the installation of typings worked.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I failed to mention I'm working on a Mac, if that's important to note. Nevertheless, even after reinstalling the latest nodejs version and node-sass it still gives me the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if that makes a difference but try "npm install typings -g"